# Share to octopress?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to blog to octopress using a simple method, similar to sharing a page on facebook using http://www.facebook.com/share_options.php

I don't know if there is any way to do this (easily) ?

I am thinking a cool method would be to have a chrome extension, etc, that would be pointed to your octopress directory, and would generate a new blog post there based on the page you are sharing. You could then use this skeleton post and add further detail if necessary?

Anything like that out there?